# Remove Windows Live credentials from Microsoft Word

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-word, windows-live

I have a Windows 7 Professional 32 bits with all service packs and Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010 with all service packs.

I use OneDrive to store my docs and I open it from Internet Explorer selecting the option to open in Word.

To open it on Word I have to put my Windows Live Credentials on a dialog box. But now, I want to delete that credentials from my computer. How can I do it?

How can I delete that credentials from my computer?

I can't find them on Panel Control -> Credential Manager, because Credential manager is empty.

If I run this command:

```
rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr
```

To delete the credentials, but Word still open the document without prompting my windows live credentials.